# Adjacency matrix using grouping column

Tags: python, pandas, graph, networkx

I am currently starting to get into pandas and I was wondering, if there is a function giving me common categories of items in a DataFrame. To visualize:

These are the data I have (highly simplified example, obviously)

```
   Discipline   Person
0    football   Alanis
1    football  Bernard
2    football  Delilah
3  basketball  Charlie
4  basketball  Delilah
5      tennis  Charlie
```

And I'd like to find out, which two people share a discipline, ideally in the form of a matrix like so:

```
        Alanis  Bernard Charlie Delilah
Alanis  True    True    False   True    
Bernard True    True    False   True
Charlie False   False   True    True
Delilah True    True    True    True
```

Alternatively, it could be a function returning a list of common categories. 
I don't even know if pandas is the best tool for a task like this one (probably not), as I said, I'm quite a noob still. I do appreciate your help though. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach could be to build a network, and obtain from it the [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix):

```
import networkx as nx
from itertools import combinations, chain

L = df.groupby('Discipline').Person.agg(list)

G = nx.Graph()
L = [list(combinations(i,2)) for i in L.values.tolist()]
G.add_edges_from(chain.from_iterable(L))
```

---

```
nx.to_pandas_adjacency(G, nodelist=sorted(G.nodes())).astype(bool)

          Alanis  Bernard  Charlie  Delilah
Alanis    False     True    False     True
Bernard    True    False    False     True
Charlie   False    False    False     True
Delilah    True     True     True    False
```

If you want the diagonal values set to True, you could just add:

```
import numpy as np
out[:] = out.values + np.eye(out.shape[1], dtype=bool)

print(out)

         Alanis  Bernard  Charlie  Delilah
Alanis     True     True    False     True
Bernard    True     True    False     True
Charlie   False    False     True     True
Delilah    True     True     True     True
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you! I was missing "Adjacency Matrix" as a term in my head, so I couldn't google it..

Answer (score 0):

value_counts() function to find the unique value counts of each element in the given Series object. Output : Now we will use Series. value_counts() function to find the values counts of each unique value in the given Series object.